# (PHP) Inserted data appears in MySQL as "Array"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

[Website.](http://comfyshoulderrest.com/guestvibe/index.php)

This feels like a common problem, but it's a difficult one to Google!

As explained in the comment in the code, inserting the value was previously not a problem but stopped working when I added the additional `INSERT` queries below it.

```
$user = $_POST['name'];
$night = $_POST['club'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT day FROM nights WHERE name = '$night'");
$email = $_POST['email'];

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $date = getFullDateString($row['day']);
    $date2 = getDateString($row['day']);

}

// this one previously worked but now enters into the database with $user as "Array"
mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestlists (guest, night, date) VALUES('$user', '$night', '$date') ") or die(mysql_error());

$guest1 = $_POST['name1'];
$guest2 = $_POST['name2'];

// these were added later and work fine but seem to have had an effect on the query above
mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestlists (guest, night, date) VALUES('$guest1', '$night', '$date') ") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestlists (guest, night, date) VALUES('$guest2', '$night', '$date') ") or die(mysql_error());

foreach ($_POST as $key){
    if (is_array($key)){
        foreach ($key as $key2 => $value){
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestlists (guest, night, date) VALUES('$value', '$night', '$date') ") or die(mysql_error());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm confused, which of the 4 inserts is doing what now?

Comment: $value than is proabably an array check it with is_array. And your code asks for mysql injection all over.

Comment: Oh no, SQL Injection! Your code is very vulnerable to attacks. Please use `mysql_real_escape_string` or even better, PDO.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't looked at SQL injections yet. Any pointers in the right direction?

Comment: use the `print_r($variable)` to check all your variables before adding it in mysql query, and if it is array than get the required value with `$variable['key']`. And BTW Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename the guest HTML inputs to `guests[]` instead of using `name` again. You have a naming conflict.

You need to fix this in your javascript code:

```
var name = $("<p><input class='input' type='text' name='guests[]' value='' /></p>");
```

And in your HTML code:

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="guests[]" />
```

After that, your PHP code should handle the guest variable as an array:

```
$guests = $_POST['guests'];

foreach ($guests as $guest)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestlists (guest, night, date) VALUES('$guest', '$night', '$date') ") 
    or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Note that you don't need to go `guests[1]`, `guests[2]`, `guests[3]` etc.

Comment: This is the tidiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

in your website you have:

```
<input class='input' type='text' name='name["+currentArrayNum+"]' value='' />
```

to generate the form. The `name[...]` arguments end up in php as `$_POST['name']` which will be an array. If you force this to be a string, the string will be `Array`. So take your `$user` and iterate over it using `foreach`, to handle each name.

Also, please read up on sql injection!

Answer (score 0):

You have some Javascript on your page that is inserting form fields that look like this:

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="name[5]" value="">
```

The `name="name[5]"` part is whats causing your problems here - it turns `$_POST['name']` in to an array when submitted. You'll need to refactor that code.